# Primary output is "obj" folder instead of "bin"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, installation

I am trying to create installer file by Visual Studio 2015 Installer.
When I add `Primary output from <project name>` into `Application Folder`, it point to files in `obj` folder instead of `bin` folder.

After installed, I can NOT start my application. I think the reason come from "obj/Release".

Please refer to attached image for more information:

[image]

Why? How can I change it to `bin` folder?

Comment: That is an obscure but accurate detail.  You forgot to mention what goes wrong.  Btw, this is one of many reasons why the Setup feature was removed at VS2012.  You can edit the .vdproj file with a text editor if that is really necessary.

Comment: @HansPassant I added image for this issue.

Comment: We already know what it looks like, we still don't know what actually goes wrong.

Comment: This had me scratching for a while. My output dlls run through a post processor called UnmanagedExports. so the setup deployed the wrong files. I even changed the vdproj file but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to forget about primary output and just add the files you want by browsing to them from the IDE's File System view, especially if it's just one or two files, and it typically help to see the files you're installing and know exactly what you're doing. Also, note that other files (such as data files) should most likely be installed to user's application data (not Application Folder), and shared Dlls might need to be in common files folder, and assemblies into the GAC. Using primary output tends to gloss over this kind of detail.

Comment: liked the suggestion but did not answer question